# FlowLayout() doesn't compile for some reason? (java) (Relatively new so don't slay me if it's obvious)

Tags: java, jframe, layout-manager

Okay, so, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get c.setLayout(new FlowLayout() to compile.  Here is the program with it's imports.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ViewMain
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double pi = Math.PI;
    int px = 0;
    int py = 0;
    int pz = 0;
    int vx = 0;
    int vy = 90;
    JFrame window = new JFrame("PrTR");
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 300, 100);

    Point aXTest = new Point(4,0,2,px,py,pz,vx,vy);
    Perspective panel = new Perspective(px,py,pz,vx,vy); 

    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   // System.out.print((int)((double)(300)*(((Math.atan((pz-3)/(px-4))-Math.toRadians(vx)))/(pi/4))));
    Container c = window.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.add(panel);
    c.add(aXTest);



    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

It seems as though I may not have imported something, but it doesn't make sense because Layout Manager tutorials showed this line of code like it was nothing.

Comment: `It seems as though I may not have imported something` - well where did you import "FlowLayout"? `Layout Manager tutorials showed this line of code like it was nothing.` - but did you look at the imports that are also part of the tutorial?

Comment: Please remember that main purpose of Stack Overflow is to be searchable repository of programming questions and answers. So to make it possible for people with similar problem find this question please add details like exact error message. Also saying only things like "can't compile/doesn't work" is not enough for us to know what problem specifically you are referring to which limits your chances of getting proper answers (more info: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).